# Including an R package onto LaTeX

Tags: errors, packages

I am a novice with using Knitr and Overleaf, and am trying to include some of my sample R code onto my .Rtex file.  The only issue I am having is trying to include an installed package onto Overleaf.  It is given below:

```
install.packages("daewr")
library(daewr)
```

Can someone please explain in a detailed and clear way on how Overleaf can recognize the package?  Thank you kindly!

Comment: I guess that only the admin group can install R packages ...

Comment: Hi Fran, do you know how to contact the admin group (if this is a proposed solution)?  I appreciate your help!

Comment: I didn't want to propose that  really, since I guess  more feasible  work off-line with your own R and RStudio, but you can try your luck at https://www.overleaf.com/contact